# How do you create a SwiftyJSON dictionary out of optional AnyObjects?

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary, swifty-json, object-initializers

I recently ran into a very time-consuming issue for a simple task of creating a `JSON dictionary` with `optional objects`. I'm using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#requirements).

If I create the following `dictionary`, I get thrown errors

> JSON type doesn't have an initializer that supports Dictionary`<String,AnyObject?>`

But if I simply change `AnyObject` to an `non-optional` type, it works.

```
var dict: Dictionary <String, AnyObject?> = [

      "title" : title as? AnyObject,
      "date" : date as? AnyObject,
]

var jsonData: JSON = JSON(dict)   // this is where I get the error
```

I need to actually a `JSON` data set that potentially has `nil` values, but it seems like `SwiftyJSON` doesn't allow it.

Is there any way I can create a `JSON dictionary` with `optional objects` using `SwiftyJSON`?

Answer (score 2):

**Neither any key nor any value of a Swift `Dictionary` can be `nil`.**

You could declare the variable as optional

```
  var dict: Dictionary <String, AnyObject>?
```